# How to fit width image with datagridcell width

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

This is my problem : The only way to select the row is to click on the image (green circle).

What I would like to do : When I click on the `DataGridCell`, not only the image, the entire row is selected.

I have `DataGridTemplateColumn` to display images in `DataGrid`.

I setted `SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"` as DataGrid properties.

But if I don't click EXACTLY on the image, the row won't be selected.

---

**SCREESHOTS**

I made some screenshots to explain it more clearly :

Size of the image : 
[image: Image size]

Size of the DataGridCell
[image: Row size]

---

So, in my opinion, the problem can come from 2 things :

- The size image doesn't fit the entire `cell`, so that's why, but how can I fit it ?
- The `Cell` select is disabled, and I can enabled it

Thanks for your time !

---

**EDIT 1**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource }" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding}">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <Image Source="{Binding }" Style="{DynamicResource }" /> 
               </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Put a `Grid` around your `Image` in the `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set the `background` to `Transparent`.

Comment: Already did. I added to show how I created the `DataGridTemplateColumn`

Comment: I don't know where's your problem: http://i.imgur.com/geyme06.gif

Comment: Strange, but it means that the problem come from something I added... Thanks you @Dominic, I'll post answer when I'll found !

Comment: You can post your DataGridStyle and HeaderStyle so that we can look it up.

Comment: I posted as answer, it was due to the `Template` property... When I apply it, I lose the way to click around the image...

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to know what it was about :

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

This made the image bug... I don't know why, but it loses the effect to click around the image... Don't know more, I used another way to add `Padding` to rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Margin` instead of `Padding`.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Grid Margin="5,1">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I don't see any changes.. It's better than `Padding`, but with or without `Margin`, it's the same thing :/